# C# SqlDbType.Datetime getting empty rows

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008, datetime, report, sqldataadapter

I develop a inventory management application. It have been in use almost for 1 year. But I decided to test some report, so I make a back up of the Database that runs in SQL server 2008 express. When I run the app im my pc I get empty rows, but when I run it in the store I get results, also if I remove the dateime range it give me data.

I use the next code for the reports:

```
frmReporteSurtido repmi = new frmReporteSurtido();
 string query = "SELECT * from [SAIV].[dbo].Vista_MovInv ";

query = query + "WHERE (FechaHora BETWEEN  @Horai AND @Horaf ) and idTiposdeMovimiento=1 and Concepto='TRANSFERENCIA DE ALMACÉN'";

            if (!cbTS.Checked)
                query = query + " AND SUCURSAL='" + idSucursalesComboBox.Text + "' ";
            if (!cbTA.Checked)
                query = query + " AND ALMACÉN='" + idAlmacenesComboBox.Text + "' ";
            if (!cbTU.Checked)
                query = query + " AND UBICACIÓN='" + comboBox1.Text + "' ";

            this.DSTCON.Vista_MovInv.Clear();
            try
            {
                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(clsData.strConexion);
                SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();

                adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand(query, conn);
                DateTime d1 = new DateTime(dateTimePicker1.Value.Year, dateTimePicker1.Value.Month, dateTimePicker1.Value.Day, 00, 00, 00);
                DateTime d2 = new DateTime(dateTimePicker2.Value.Year, dateTimePicker2.Value.Month, dateTimePicker2.Value.Day, 23, 59, 59);
                adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@Horai",SqlDbType.DateTime).Value= d1;
                adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@Horaf",SqlDbType.DateTime).Value=d2;
                adapter.Fill(DSTCON.Vista_MovInv);
            }
            catch (Exception ec) { DataControl.Guardar_Error(ec, this.Name); }

            repmi.crptSurtido1.SetDataSource(this.DSTCON);
            repmi.MdiParent = this.MdiParent;
            repmi.Show();
```

I think is a date time issue, but I can't find it. The two server(One in the store and the other in my house) have the same collation. Also I change my regional settings in my home server and myu pc but nothing happens.

Thank's for your Help.

Comment: Well, I can't tell why your having this error, but I can tell for sure your application is crying for an SQL Injection. 
http://imgs.xkcd.com/comics/exploits_of_a_mom.png

Answer (score 1):

:( So silly.

The error was here:

```
string query = "SELECT * from [SAIV].[dbo].Vista_MovInv ";
```

I named the back up I restore like this:

```
[SAIV_TAM];
```

So I was trying to get info from the database whit no new data.

Also my stored procedure that modify inventories was pointing to my development database and not to the back up, and because the the database at my workplace and my home have the same name, i encounter the problem when I rename it.

Thank's for your help and sorry for my dumbness.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you PC has the different datetime(language) formate with database.You should change the datetime formate to  'yyyy-MM-dd'.

Comment: I insert a new record to check the datime value And I get this

Comment: the two servers settings of datetime are dd/MM/yyyy, my pc was MM/dd/yyyy, so I changed it, but nothing happens. Also the datetime value in the revers are like this: 2013-05-08 21:05:18.827

Comment: you should set the same formate of datetime between your pc and database.

Answer (score 0):

Change the following lines:

```
adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@Horai",SqlDbType.DateTime).Value= d1;
adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@Horaf",SqlDbType.DateTime).Value=d2;
```

to

```
adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@Horai",SqlDbType.DateTime).Value= new SqlDateTime(d1);
adapter.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@Horaf",SqlDbType.DateTime).Value= new SqlDateTeim(d2);
```